# Python - importing text file to a list

Tags: python, list, import

First off I am aware this kind of question has already been posted but none of those things seemed to be working for me.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
"foo","bar","green","white"
```

and so on.
I want to import the entire content to a list like this:

```
txtfile = open("H:/Python/colors.txt", "r")
list1 = [txtfile.read()]

print (list1[0])
```

but python does not recognize the words as seperate list items, so that `list1[0]` gives me the entire content and `list1[1]` does not exist.

Why does python do that and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to specify separately list and can write as:

```
with open("stopwords.txt", "r") as fd:
    var = fd.readline()
list1 = list()
temp = eval(var)
list1 = [ele for ele in temp]
print(list1)
```

Explanation:

Read the line using `readline` and get that into `var` and that is a `string` datatype. Now using `eval` evaluate it. Now using `list comprehension` you can get required output

Comment: uh, the code you posted is the same as mine but without the [] - now it only prints the first character (") though

Comment: yes, print(list1[1]) gives me the correct answer - thanks

Comment: @FlyingThunder: Thanks for confirming. Please accept it as your required answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
list1 = txtfile.read().split(',')
```

Comment: thanks, didnt think of a split, thought python would detect the list syntax

Comment: @FlyingThunder string is string, it won't become other things until you explicitly call some methods.

Comment: actually i still have a problem - the text file i am importing is a long list of colors, but after removing all unnecessary white spaces and quotes, python (tkinter) gives me this:

`_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "
orange3"`

so every color that is the first in a line doesnt get recognized - does python handle a new line as a specific character?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
txtfile = open("H:/Python/colors.txt", "r")
list1 = txtfile.read().split(",")
print(list1[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the mentioned below code:

```
file=open("H:/Python/colors.txt","r")
for line in file:
    fields=line.split(",")
print(fields[0],fields[1],fields[2],fields[3])
```